# I have a div with that doesn't grow with content

Tags: css

I have a main div that has a background-color. I put a login window in that div with a width:675px; height:300px; Also have margins for the top/bottom of the window. The background isn't growing to accommodate the div. here's the code i'm using:

```
  <div class="main">
    <div class="topLine"></div>
    <div class="loginWindow">
      <div class="logo">
        TEXT
      </div>

    </div>

    <div style="clear: both"></div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #152d47, #467ba7);
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  padding-top:8px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.loginWindow {
  margin:0 auto; 
  width:675px;
  margin-top:172px;
  margin-bottom:115px;
  height:300px;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grem28/uj5zbhf7/

Comment: Remove `height: 100px` from `.main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **height** of parent if you want that it can to grow or change it to **min-height**

Comment: @Damien in my browser it working nice, top | bottom margin of loginWindow - http://joxi.ru/5mdW5G6h6bWar1

Answer (score 0):

well, use `overflow:visible;` instead of `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your height to 100% and remove the overflow, or change it to visible. Here's the CSS with overflow commented out.

```
.main {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #152d47, #467ba7); 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding-top:8px;
  /* overflow: visible; */
}
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uj5zbhf7/4/